# Arba'a Ushloshim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred thirty-four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Following Hitler's decision in October 1942 to make Germany "free of Jews" ("judenfrei"), [the SS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schutzstaffel) transported most of [Buchenwald](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchenwald_concentration_camp)'s remaining 650 Jews to [Auschwitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auschwitz_concentration_camp). Two hundred thirty-four remained.

[Bill Niven, *The Buchenwald Child*, page 13](http://books.google.com/books?id=PJ4ANr2oLpwC&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=auschwitz) (internal footnote omitted).

Answer (score 3):

In a non-leap year, *Yom Yerushalayim* is the 234th day in the year if *Heshvan* and *Kislev* are both *Haserim* (have 29 days):

*Tishrei* -30 days
*Heshvan*, *Kislev*, *Tevet* - 29 days each
*Shvat* - 30 days
*Adar* - 29 days
*Nisan* - 30 days
*Iyar* - 28 days (*Yom Yerushalayim* is on the 28th day of *Iyar*)

Answer (score 0):

234+ years ago, on July 4, 1776 the United States was formed after the Declaration of Independence. This Medina Shel Chesed is the last stop prior to Moshiach per many of the Gedolim.

Comment: I'd love to see sources for your second point.

Answer (score 0):

When Vayakhel and Pekudei are read together on Shabbat Parshat Hachodesh. Note that this occurs only in regular years when Pesach falls on either Tuesday or Thursday.

The total reading consists of 234 verses as follows:

Vayakhel    122
Pekudei      92
Hachodesh    20

Total = 234

Comment: Mattot/Masei is 244

Comment: @DoubleAA +3 for maftir, if you want to count that separately for consistency.  Or +7 if it's Rosh Chodesh, if that can happen (Tisha Beav would be Sunday not nidcheh, which can happen, but I don't know if Matot-Masei can be together in that case).

Comment: @DoubleAA Thabnks for the correction. I missed that total from the parsha stats chart that I was viewing.